# Excel 2007 macro: vb throws runtime '91' error when storing value in an array

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

Following is the code, in an excel 2007 macro, throwing me `RunTime error '91' Object variable or With block variable not set` :

```
Dim Balance(3, 12, 1) As Object
    Balance(0, 0, 0) = "abL"
    Balance(1, 0, 0) = "cd"
    Balance(2, 0, 0) = "ef"
    Balance(3, 0, 0) = "gh"
```

I am new to vb. Please help.

P.S I have worked with Java, C#, C, PHP and a bit of assembly too but have never felt so uncomfortable with any of them as much as VB. May be today is a bad day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is very simple. You have declared the array an an `Object`. Declare it as a `String` as you are storing `String` values in it. Try this. This works

```
Public Sub Sample()
    Dim Balance(3, 12, 1) As String 'Or Variant
    Balance(0, 0, 0) = "abL"
    Balance(1, 0, 0) = "cd"
    Balance(2, 0, 0) = "ef"
    Balance(3, 0, 0) = "gh"
End Sub
```

For further reading: [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716185%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

**Followup from comments**

> I will be storing String and numbers in the same multidimensional array, hence, i need to keep the type Object –  Salik 4 mins ago

In such a case use

```
Dim Balance(3, 12, 1) As Variant
```

For example this works for me.

```
Public Sub Sample()
    Dim Balance(3, 12, 1) As Variant
    Balance(0, 0, 0) = "abL"
    Balance(1, 0, 0) = 1
    Balance(2, 0, 0) = "ef"
    Balance(3, 0, 0) = 2
End Sub
```

For Further reading: [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251448.aspx) about Variant Data Type

Comment: no, that i cant. I need it to Object type array. I will be storing String and numbers in the same multidimensional array, hence, i need to keep the type Object

Comment: @Salik: Then use `Variant` as shown in the comment (in code) above

Comment: Using variant gives me another error when storing numbers into it. `Runtime '438'.Object does not support this property or method.`

Comment: @Salik: I just tested it and it works. Refresh the page to see my updated answer.

Comment: Yup, my bad. could you please explain me why does not it work with Object type but works with Variant type? Although the article you linked treated both as the same.

Comment: @Salik: I have updated the link. This will give you a better picture :) You might have to refresh the page :)